# Pivot table cannot create calculated item

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I've encountered a problem with pivot tables in Excel.

I want to create calculated item, but it does not allow me, as it says `This Pivot report field is grouped`

But it's **not** grouped in any way.

I even tried to copy my data to new workbook. It contains only one names in `rows`, months in `columns` and one single value as `value`. I've never grouped anything, but it is still consider this table as grouped.

Does anyone know, why that could be? Thanks!

Comment: I've successfully reproduced the **Calculated Field** for both  **Grouped Pivot Table**,,  and for **Grouped Items**,check my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

On the actual pivot table, right click the columns months, select `Ungroup`

[image]

Let me know if this does not work and I will remove this answer.

Comment: @Marqz I get the same issue when ever I use a date field in a pivot table, it seems to group the column by default

Answer (score 0):

**It's possible to create `Calculated Field` for `Grouped Pivot Table.`**

[image]

*With attached Screen Shot you can find everything,*

- Source Data.
- Pivot Table(Grouped) without Calculated field.
- PT with Calculated Field.
- Dialog to Insert Calculated Field.

**Note,**

- *It's needless to illustrate the required steps since you are aware with the process.*
- *Alter the equation for Calculated Field and Source Data Range as your need.*

**Edited:**

**This portion is showing that how can you generate Calculated Field for `Groped Items`.**

*In below shown Screen Shot you can find `Calculated Field` **Sum Of Grouped Items** in red color.*

Also check the **Insert Calculated Item dialog** for the Calculate field.

[image]

**How it Works:**

- Select anywhere in PT & from **PT ANALYZE Tab** find & hit **Fields, Items & Sets**.
- Next, Select **Calculated Items**
- At the **Insert Calculated Items Dialog**, in the **Formula Text box** select any **Grouped Field/Fields** to compose the required Formula.

**N.B.**

- Check the Screen Shot I've used 2 Calculated items **ABC & DEF**.
- *If still you find any issue write in Comments I'll extend the help.*